# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable on second call to array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working on a project for a Python class and I've hit a wall.

I have a function that generates some statistics from an array of numbers. On the first call, this works fine. On subsequent calls, I get an error.

These are the two pertinent excerpts from a much larger file.

```
def generateStats(column):
    column = np.array(column).astype(np.float)
    count = column.size
    mean = np.mean(column)
    deviation = np.std(column)
    minimum = min(column)
    maximum = max(column)
    return count, mean, deviation, minimum, maximum
```

...

```
if operationChoice == '1':
                popApr1Array = []
                for run, line in enumerate(result):
                    popApr1Array.append(line.popApr1)
                count, mean, deviation, min, max = generateStats(popApr1Array)
                print(f'Count: {count}\nMean: {mean}\n' \
                f'Standard Deviation: {deviation}\nMin: {min} \nMax: {max}\n')
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
Select the column to analyze:
1. Pop Apr 1
2. Pop Jul 1
3. Change Pop
4. Exit application

Enter the number that indicates your selection: 1
Count: 557
Mean: 56557.314183123875
Standard Deviation: 157985.09635030487
Min: 13519.0 
Max: 3726157.0

Select the column to analyze:
1. Pop Apr 1
2. Pop Jul 1
3. Change Pop
4. Exit application

Enter the number that indicates your selection: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/Week 5/Week5DataAnalysis.py", line 95, in <module>
    count, mean, deviation, min, max = generateStats(popApr1Array)
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/Week 5/Week5DataAnalysis.py", line 55, in generateStats
    minimum = min(column)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Any advice?

Comment: I'm relatively sure that something is missing here

Comment: I can't see any way in which you get past `deviation = np.std(column)` in the example you've given if you actually passed a string.

Comment: I changed the variable names "min" and "max" to "minimum" and "maximum" and now it works on every call. I guess it had something to do with using a variable name that shadowed a function name... not sure how or why. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: You've got it answered. I saw it in `return` but didn't spot the global shadowing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
count, mean, deviation, min, max = generateStats(popApr1Array)
```

You are renaming `min`.
It is no longer referring to a python standard library function but to a value returned by `generateStats`.